# Using Unique IDs to Create User Row, R

Tags: r

I have a large set of data and I have run into a problem while trying to organize it in R. I need my data to be in a long string instead of in a column. I have one column with user IDs and another column full of data. There is one user id per X number of entries. Is there a way to rotate the cells in the column according to the individual ID? I would also Like for each of the values to be in an individual cell per ID.

Here is what the data looks like now:

```
user1 123  
na     234
na     345
user2 455
na     678
user3 87
na      987
user4 676
na    456
na    78
na    356
```

And Here is what I am looking to accomplish:

```
User 1  123 124 142 345 23  343
User 2  534 56              
User 3  7567 354 7667 56        
User 4  34
```

I am currently using R for the majority of my analysis but if there is a better suited program to use, I am open to using it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your entry data is the same as your output. Also, please do not post pictures. Use `dput()` instead.

Comment: It seems that you aren't using R for this yet (?). Do you have this in a reproducible format (so we can run R code and see the example data)?

Comment: I just tired to edit it, it is quite hard to try to create a readable format here! I am using R for the other parts of this project. I am currently trying to format this last bit of data and i have done all other formatting in R so far. Let me know if the above is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 fill(V1) %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 summarise(V2 = toString(V2))

  V1    V2               
  <chr> <chr>            
1 user1 123, 234, 345    
2 user2 455, 678         
3 user3 87, 987          
4 user4 676, 456, 78, 356
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 fill(V1) %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 summarise(V2 = paste(V2, collapse = ", "))
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "user1 123  
na     234
                 na     345
                 user2 455
                 na     678
                 user3 87
                 na      987
                 user4 676
                 na    456
                 na    78
                 na    356", header = FALSE,
                 na.strings = c("na"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Or dealing with `na` after reading the data in:

```
df %>%
 mutate(V1 = na_if(V1, "na")) %>%
 fill(V1) %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 summarise(V2 = toString(V2))
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "user1 123  
na     234
                 na     345
                 user2 455
                 na     678
                 user3 87
                 na      987
                 user4 676
                 na    456
                 na    78
                 na    356", header = FALSE,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Threw a error, not sure if it is on my end. "Error: unexpected '=' in:" before ToString. This is great though.

Comment: Could be a typo. It is `toString` not `ToString`.

Comment: Its a data problem on my end it looks like. Your example works great but adding in my data is the problem. Let me see if I can find the problem.

Comment: Updated my post with a different approach. Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Works great! I fixed the issue, the last main question i have is can I separate all those values into individual cells in that row?

Comment: That is basically a different question. You can do `df %>%
 fill(V1) %>%
 gather(var, val, -V1) %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 mutate(var = paste(var, gl(n(), 1), sep = "_")) %>%
 spread(var, val)`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear in the original question. I found a way to separate them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the data once it is reformatted, in any case, it will remain almost unusable.

```
# load packages
library(data.table)

# create data
dt <- fread("user1 123
na     234
na     345
user2 455
na     678
user3 87
na      987
user4 676
na    456
na    78
na    356")

# change the character string na to real NAs
dt[V1 == "na", V1 := NA]

# fill in the empty cells with the last observed value
library(zoo)
dt[, V1 := na.locf(V1)]
```

## Now the formatting part:

### Usable alternative 1 (although it differs from your expected output, it still can be used  for some purposes)

```
dcast(dt, V1 ~ V2)
```

### Usable alternative 2: put all the V2 values in a list:

```
dt[, list(.(V2)), by = V1]
```

### Printing alternative 3: paste all the values, having a long string (it's the most similar to your expected output):

```
dt[, paste(V2, collapse = "  "), by = V1]
```

Comment: These solutions also produce what is required, thanks for all the help. I now have many different ways to choose from. Thanks